# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar, nestedscrollview

Iv seen many threads like that, but non of them helped me. When i use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView im having scrolling issues - stuck. I know its because that is scroll inside scroll,

`rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` is not working for me.
on few thread there was information that NestedScrollView dont have to be used - but then toolbar is not collapsing.

My XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTopic"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <RelativeLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:alpha="0.5"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_white" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/yourVotes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:text="@string/YourVotes"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

                            android:text="1" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </FrameLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground">

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/VotesSum"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/TodayVotes"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/TodayAdded"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/tracks_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So, please help me to make that work

```
public class PlaylistDetailActivityWithoutFragmet extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView votesLeft;
    private RecyclerView lvTracks;
    private SinglePlaylistFragment_.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    SinglTracksAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    final ArrayList<PlaylistTracks> playlistsTracks = new ArrayList<PlaylistTracks>();
    final ArrayList<PlaylistTracks> playlistsTracks2 = new ArrayList<PlaylistTracks>();
    int lastId = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Toolbar toolbarDetails;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private int visibleThreshold = 2;
    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    int height;
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.Playlist);

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    //  mTextMessage.setText(R.string.Statistics);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    //    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.Users);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_coordinator_layout);




        toolbarDetails = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarDetails);
        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarDetails);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(playlistName);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        toolbarDetails.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        toolbarDetails.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebSocketClient.close();
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });



        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);


       //  nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);


        lvTracks = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tracks_recycler_view);
        lvTracks.setLayoutManager(llm);
        lvTracks.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

//       nestedScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarDetails);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loading = true;
        getTracks();
        lvTracks.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                visibleItemCount = llm.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.i("dx", String.valueOf(dx));
                Log.i("dy", String.valueOf(dy));
                Log.i("visibleItemCount", String.valueOf(visibleItemCount));
                Log.i("firstVisibleItem", String.valueOf(firstVisibleItem));
                Log.i("totalItemCount", String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {


                    loading = true;

                    getMoreTracks(1, 2);
                }
            }
        });

//
//        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
//                if (!loading && v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
//                    if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
//                            scrollY > oldScrollY) {
//                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        loading = true;
//
//                        getMoreTracks(scrollX, scrollY);
//
//
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        });



        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mWebSocketClient.close();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }






    }

}
```

Updated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTopic"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <RelativeLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:alpha="0.5"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_white" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/yourVotes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:text="@string/YourVotes"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/votesSum"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

                            android:text="1" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </FrameLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/tracks_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why would you need a recyclerView to be into a NestedScrollView? Also please upload your `Main_Activity.java` class

Comment: If i dont have to it would be great, but when there is no NestedScrollView - like on XML above the toolbar is not collapsing. When it is - scrolling issues :(

Comment: A recyclerView is already scrollable by itself, why should you use a NestedScrollView too?

Comment: Without NestedScrollView toolbar dont collapse in my case

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use below line in your activity class:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycler_view, false);
```

its compatible for lower versions also. and if you want to give compatible to API >21 only then use;

```
recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your final objective is to have the ToolBar diasappear/collapse when you scroll on the recyclerView, you should not use NestedScrollView, but CoordinatorLayout instead.

Have a look [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout).

Here is a quick example taken from the doc I provided on how to create a collapsing toolbar.

Firstly in your xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Make sure that in your Activity, in your `onCreate()` you set it the right way:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
              (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
 collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: as from above XML, I should just replace LinearLayout with CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: No, not only, please read the link I provided. It will guide you through the code

Comment: Problem solved, it was lvTracks.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);